# Cordova run es6 code

Tags: cordova, ecmascript-6

I've created a new cordova project with `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld` command and I've also added the needed platforms (android and browser).
In index.js I've changed `initialize` member as follows: 
     `document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => { alert('test');});`

Application runs as expected when is started with `cordova run browser` and `cordova run android --device`.

When application is started in android emulator (Nexus_5X_API_23.avd) I get

## `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`# error.

I've tried so far:
`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime
npm install --save babel-runtime
.babelrc file created with {"plugins": ["transform-runtime"]} text`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, you don't have to transpile your code first with Babel? From what I'm reading you should still transpile your code prior to including (the transpiled) into your app. I'm not overly familiar with Cordova apps, but I know I need to do the same on any web project or an Electron app.

Comment: BTW, here's the reference where I saw that https://shellmonger.com/2015/11/24/apache-cordova-es2015-and-babel/

Comment: Thank you for your comment Steve! The idea is that same code runs well on browser, android and ios devices and fails on android and ios emulators. It seems like I should enable something for the emulators.

Comment: Yes, if you transpile your source code first, and include your transpiled file, then it should work in any of those environments. The Babel transpiler takes your ES6 code and converts it to ES5 (which is usable in each instance). Sort of a necessary hack until all the browser creators get completely up to spec, and all of the legacy browsers finally die off.